# Extraxt Diagonal matrix into a Row Vecotor not a Column Vector

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following formula works when I drag down, however how would i change it for it to work when I drag horizontally.

I am looking for diagonally down to the right values to appear in a row.

=INDEX(B40:V40,,ROWS($21:21))

Thanks

Comment: Make index array absolute try `=INDEX($B$40:$V$40,,ROWS($21:21))`

Comment: @Harun24hr I dont the correct reference celss, it just produces this 0.00602 0.00602 0.00602. Rather than across 0.00602 0.006373027 0.006728161 0.007072971 0.007424427

Comment: You could do `=INDEX(B40:B60,COLUMNS($B:B))`. Or if (since) you can write your formula as `=INDEX($B$40:$V$60,ROWS($1:1),ROWS($1:1))` then the solution could be 
`=INDEX($B$40:$V$60,COLUMNS($B:B),COLUMNS($B:B))`.